# openpyxl: remove_sheet causes IndexError: list index out of range error on saving sheet

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to use openpyxl to:

1. Open an Excel (2016) workbook which contains 3 worksheets (Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3)
2. Remove a worksheet (Sheet2)
3. Save the workbook to a different workbook minus Sheet2

   ```
   from openpyxl import load_workbook
   wb = load_workbook("c:/Users/me/book1.xlsx")
   ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
   wb.remove_sheet(ws)
   wb.save("c:/Users/me/book2.xlsx")
   ```

The `wb.save` will generate an `IndexError: list index out of range` error and produce a corrupted book2.xlsx file which Excel cannot open.

Comment: If you think there is a bug then you should submit a bug report.

Comment: I am new to openpyxlI am happy to submit a bug report but just wanted to make sure my code is valid usage of openpyxl.

Comment: Code looks okay, though `del wb['Sheet2']` is an easier way to work. You'll need to supply a file.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/748/openpyxl-remove_sheet-causes-indexerror#comment-None

Comment: Thanks ! Bug report filed with additional details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run into similar problem, only with `xlwt` library. Regardless, the cause is the same, You remove the sheet which is set as active sheet. So, to fix this, before saving workbook, set some other sheet as active. In `openpyxl`, it would be something like this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("c:/Users/me/book1.xlsx")
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
wb.remove_sheet(ws)
wb._active_sheet_index = 0
wb.save("c:/Users/me/book2.xlsx")
```

I must mention that this is not very good programming practice, but there is no method to set active sheet, only to get one.

EDIT: Just found out that this repo was moved to `bitbucket`, and found that it has method for setting active sheet. Just use:

```
wb.active = 0
```